# Syntax error on System.out.println( ) - Invalid token

Tags: java, syntax

just started learning Java and bumping into syntax issue.

```
import java.util.*;

public class sum_to_n {
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        int n = 5;
        int result = sumOfNaturals(n);
        System.out.println("Sum is " result); // Error Syntax error on token "result", delete this token

    }

    public static int sumOfNaturals(int input){
        int sum =0;
        for ( int i =0; i<=input; i++) {
            sum += i;
        }
        return sum;
    }

}
```

In the System.out.println statement , i am getting an error saying "Syntax error on token "result", delete this token"

Answer (score 1):

You need a + in between different variables to concatenate them. In this case, your literal `String` is a variable, as well as result. Simply:

```
    System.out.println("Sum is " + result);
```

Comment: Yep ! that worked... 3 answers within one minute ! awesome :) thanks all

Answer (score 1):

You need concatenate using `+` operator

```
 System.out.println("Sum is "+ result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to concatenate the strings, use the `+` sign like

```
System.out.println("Sum is " + result);
```